# Do "smelly cheese", "sour cheese", and "sharp cheese" have the same meaning?

Tags: meaning

I noticed that "smelly", "sour", and "sharp" are all used to modify cheese. Are they of the same meaning?

I looked up "sharp" in dictionary and found it can be defined as:

> acidic and intense.

Then the "sharp cheese" is just the "sour cheese" or "smelly cheese", right?

And an off-topic question: Is goats' milk cheese usually sour or "sharp"?

Comment: "Sharp" is a flavor that is associated primarily with aging of cheese, so if by goat's milk cheese you're thinking of something like Chevre, then "sharp" is not the word you're looking for. That said, I'm not sure "sour" is the correct word either: tartness is not a desirable characteristic for most cheeses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While *smelly*, *sharp*, and *sour* may have some overlap, they all refer to distinct concepts.

*Smelly*, i.e. having a noticeable and disagreeable odor, does not describe any distinctive flavor. Crushed garlic is smelly in an entirely different way from rotten fish.

The [Wisconsin Cheese Glossary](http://www.eatwisconsincheese.com/cheese/Glossary.aspx), a project of the Wisconsin Milk Marketing Board, distinguishes between *sharp* and *sour*:

> **Sharp** A descriptive flavor term referring to the fully developed flavor of aged cheeses, such as Cheddar, Provolone and some Blue-veined varieties. The flavor is actually sharp and biting, but not excessively acrid or sour.
>
> **Sour** A descriptive term for cheese with an excessive acid content. However, a mild, tangy, sour flavor can be attractive in young cheeses. Tartness is the same as sourness in flavors.

I'm sure cheese connoisseurs have their own language for describing the "notes" of particular cheeses, as do wine aficionados. Of interest may be "[Flavor description and classification of selected natural
cheeses](http://krex.k-state.edu/dspace/bitstream/handle/2097/2225/Flavor_Descri_Class_natural_cheese.pdf;jsessionid=1D0B678AACAEDFB5D6032E5B1C8744A6?sequence=1)" by Delores H. Chambers, Edgar Chambers IV, and Dallas Johnson in *Culinary Arts and Sciences V: Global and National Perspectives*, 2005; as well as "[Describing Flavor Using Fewer and Simpler "HITs" (High Identity Traits) Profiling: An Example with Cheese](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1745-459X.2010.00281.x/abstract)," by the same authors with Martin Talavera-Bianchi, in the *Journal of Sensory Studies*, Volume 25, Issue 4, August 2010. The latter was [made into an infographic](http://seanseidell.com/2012/07/15/infographics-2/cheese-poster/) last year that seems never to be presented in high enough resolution to be any use online.

Comment: There is actually a category of types of cheese that are characterized first and foremost by being smelly: Limburger comes to mind. They're related to, but somewhat different than, the moldy-rind soft cheeses like Brie and Camembert.